# How can I validate a radio button?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a radio button in my Rails application:

```
.<% @votes.each do |vote| %>

   .<%= radio_button_tag "escolha", "#{vote.id}" %>

.<% end %>
```

I want to make a java-script code that validates this when no option is chosen.

Comment: You mean you want to disallow people from submitting the form if no radio button is selected -- is that right?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off with a drop-down list, which would force the user to select an option?  [Take a look at the docs for the select tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

Comment: Why use javascript when you can use `validates` method in rails itself?

Comment: Something like this: `validates :votes, :presence => true`

Comment: @RenatoShumi, please accept it as answer if it had helped you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your votes class do something similar to this:

```
    class Myvotes < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :votes, :presence => true
    end
```

Please refer to the [8.2 Validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) section of the Rails release notes, [this tutorial](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/31/validates_rails_3_awesome_is_true), and the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: His question specifically asks for a **JavaScript** solution.  Clearly he'll need to validate on the server too, but they're two different contexts.

Comment: @Pointy, I asked if he could use `validates` method in a comment & for that he asked how, I answered! :)

Comment: Yes @Dave that appears to be true - I'm not sure the questioner totally "gets" SO yet :-)