# Vaidation Radio Button Tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a radio_button_tag in my rails project, and I want to make a validation when no option is chosen.

```
<% @votes.each do |vote| %>

  <%= radio_button_tag "escolha", "#{vote.id}" %>

<% end %>
```

HOw can I do that?

Comment: How is this different from your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976958/how-can-i-validate-a-radio-button

Comment: i really need this using javascript

Comment: Your other question is still open however.  Just add to it, reject the non-JavaScript answers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Form1_Validator(theForm)
{
// require at least one radio button be selected
var radioSelected = false;
for (i = 0;  i < theForm.votes.length;  i++)
  {
if (theForm.votes[i].checked)
radioSelected = true;
  }
if (!radioSelected)
  {
alert("Please select one of the \"Vote\" options.");
return (false);
  }
}
```

For javascript you can use something like above. For Rails you can see my answer in your other question.